# Combining Codeigniter routes with regex

Tags: regex, codeigniter, routes

I've been playing around with creating an e-commerce site with Codeigniter, and am trying to do the following:

Have category names as the first parameter, e.g.

- `/tshirts`
- `/shoes`

following each of these, is either a filter (on the category), or the product (with category in URL for SEO)

- `/tshirts/filter/price/0-20`
- `/tshirts/pink-with-blue-spots`

What I’m currently doing in the routing is this:

```
$route['tshirts']                    = 'category/index';
$route['tshirts/(filter|sort)']      = 'category/index';
$route['tshirts/(filter|sort)/:any'] = 'category/index/filter';
$route['tshirts/:any']               = 'product/index';
```

I want to combine the first two lines into one, as they are accessing the same controller and method.

The second line is there incase someone removes the part after `/filter/`, and could possibly be combined with another route.

The last route means the second parameter is a product name, so must be passed to the product controller.

I've been playing with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and come up with the following, which might be close, think I just need to make the part in brackets optional (it’s picking up the correct routes, except the one without any second parameter), but I'm not sure how to.

```
category/?(filter|sort|page)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not familiar with the syntax of CodeIgniter routes. But try this:

```
$route['tshirts(/(filter|sort))?']      = 'category/index';
```

And if non-capturing groups are supported:

```
$route['tshirts(?:/(filter|sort))?']      = 'category/index';
```

Comment: Tried the first one, works great, thanks. Plus I understand whats happening which is a plus :)

Answer (score 5):

Had a quick look at this today, have now combined the

```
$route['tshirts/(filter|sort)']      = 'category/index';
$route['tshirts/(filter|sort)/:any'] = 'category/index/filter';
```

into

```
$route['tshirts(/(filter|sort|page)(/(:any))?)?'] = "category/index/$4";
```

And in the `index($filter = null)` method of the category controller, use `$filter != null` to see whether the filter rules need to be applied.